# Tried moving a large angular 8 project to 9 error in declaration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular8, angular9

I am trying to move my ionic/angular 8 to 9 . I am adding few snippet of the `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts`

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
.......
................
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**ERROR**

```
 Error: error TS100: src/app/app.module.ts(45,9): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
      Referencing an exported destructured variable or constant is not supported in decorators and this value is needed by the template compiler
        Consider simplifying to avoid destructuring.
    error TS100: src/app/app.module.ts(45,9): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
      Referencing an exported destructured variable or constant is not supported in decorators and this value is needed by the template compiler
```

Based on my research I am guessing it has something to do with SYntax, I am new to ionic would be great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `AfterViewInit` on AppComponent, then instead of it replace to the Ionic life cycle [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) like `ionViewWillEnter` or `ionViewDidEnter`, no need to implement, just state as normal method and do what you have to do as you would with `AfterViewInit`.